# Failed building wheel for cryptography

Tags: python, pip, quandl

I'm trying to install [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/) on Ubuntu 16.04. I used the command `pip install quandl`, but I got a slew of errors. The first error was the one in the title and the second was `Failed cleaning build dir for cryptography`. I researched and found that someone cleared this error by using `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` to install open-ssl, but this didn't work for me. I still get the same errors.

Comment: Had exactly the same error, but on Ubuntu 14.04. Had to `$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev`.

Comment: @zezollo do you know what causes this error?

Comment: Seems to be this missing library (libffi). Some module requires some bindings to it, some functions from this library, in order to compile well. When you get the error, you can scroll up and after a while you'll see: this is written. After having installed it, I reinstalled quandl in a new venv and it worked. So, might be the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [@zezollo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3926735/zezollo) solutions in comment.

I solve this problem with `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` and there is no errors when I retry to install `cryptography` with `pip`.